# Change language in Google Maps app

Tags: google-maps, languages, 8.0-oreo, motorola-moto-z2-play

I would like to have mobile Google Maps' content on my Moto Z2 Play in different language (Polish) than rest of the system (English). Is this possible? If yes, then how to achieve this?

Based on my research and previous tries, I managed to:

- change language of audio guidance in mobile Google Maps to Polish,
- change content in desktop / PC version of Google Maps to Polish (even though my Windows 10 and Google Chrome runs in English).

However, I can't / don't know how to change content's language in mobile Google Maps.

**Edit**: *[An answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29124/change-language-for-one-application-google-now-voice-recognition-root-availabl) suggested by Robert is out of option in this particular case, because it requires device to be rooted. I don't have an ability to root the device for which I want Google Maps to run in a different langauge than the rest of the Android system.*

Comment: In the end I assume the answer is identical to this question: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29124/change-language-for-one-application-google-now-voice-recognition-root-availabl

Comment: Can you define contents in this case? Is it the streets' names or Google maps' interface? Or something else?

Comment: Everything that can be localized in the whole Google Maps application. Starting from maps and their content (street names, cities etc.) ending up in user interface. In particular I am looking for something as obvious as most applications have -- meaning to be able to select in-app language. In case of most of applications it can be different than the system language. In case of Google Maps, Google again knows better and always offers Google Maps in system-default language only.